# migrate roaming profile from server 2008 R2 Foundation to Server 2012 R2 Standard

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2012

Does anyone know of a sane way to migrate roaming user profiles from 2008 to 2012? I can not seem to get it working.

I've tried:

- robocopy
- FSMT
- cp -R
- Joining new domain, logging in, copying old data to new user.V2 folders

all to no avail. I'm consistently met with permission errors and/or the users don't have access to the data after logging in.

ADMT does not work with server 2012 so that's not an option. I can't do an in-place upgrade because it's not supported with 2008 Foundation.

It seems like it shouldn't be this hard but I can't figure it out. I've spent 2 days googling and testing with no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was:

- join new domain
- log into new domain with user
- log out
- log back in as local admin
- drag files and folders from the old `C:\Users\user.name` folder to new `C:\Users\user.name.DOMAIN` folder

however, it seems to have only partially worked which I guess is par for the course.